# Is there a formal name for the "love" of arguing?

Tags: social-psychology, personality

Most of people drop discussion easily. Some others don't. As if they would like to argue. 
They feel that they have to demonstrate something.

**Is there a formal trait to describe people who enjoy arguing and the behavior of enjoying an argument?**

Comment: I like [polemical](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/polemical) as a word, but it has little to do with cognitive science.

Extending that, polemicophilia, while not actually being a word in use, might be a nice term for what you're describing ([although 'polemikos' actually means 'war' in Greek](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=polemic)).

Comment: @Eoin: yes, polemic is another which I like. Are there no correlation between polemicity and any trait of personality? Or with any axis defined by the MMPI? Or with some of the myers briggs classification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of any clinical term for it, but a contentious individual is one who is eager to fight. Another term, pugnacious, is a little less derogatory than contentious.

Comment: Usually the pugnacious / contentious individuals share the same clinical history or some common trait? Why some people drop it and some other are really proud of their ideas and will fight to defend and share them?